# PHTML receives no response from the Ajax Controller

Tags: blocks, controllers, ajax, cms

In order to be able to load the product list according to the customers' selection, I tried to use an Ajax query. However, I have the problem that I do not receive the response from my controller. The query works, but I only get the current page as HTML code. Maybe one more important information: Via CMS I call the block as follows: `{{block class="VenSum\ModSum\Block\Index" template="VenSum_ModSum::index.phtml"}}`

index.phtml:

```
<script>
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'],function($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var categoryid = 3;
            $.ajax({
                url: myurl,
                type: "POST",
                data: {data: "hi"},
                //dataType: 'json', <- does not work with it
                success: function (msg) {
                    console.log("Works: ");
                    console.log(msg);
                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    console.log("Error Status: " + jqXHR.status + " ------- " + textStatus + "---------- " + errorThrown);
                }
            }).done(function (msg){
                console.log("Done: ");
                console.log(msg);
            }).fail(function (response){
                console.log("Fail: ");
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

controller:

```
<?php

namespace VenSum\ModSum\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {

        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax())
        {
            $test=Array
            (
                'Firstname' => 'What is your firstname',
                'Email' => 'What is your emailId',
                'Lastname' => 'What is your lastname',
                'Country' => 'Your Country'
            );
            return $result->setData($test);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you have an idea...

Comment: confirm first, does your controller called or not?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I'm getting the status code that he's coming through. But I'm not seeing any response or anything like that. So I think that the controller called but is not responding

Comment: from the controller just try to put echo "Test Responce" and then check, does it get to you or not?

Comment: No it does not get there

Comment: That means your controller is not called, so first look into this one.